# Simple DB connection via SSL in C++

Tags: c++, sql, database, ssl, https

The idea is to provide a C++ library for our clients, that opens a secure connection to one of our database-servers to make a simple (hard-coded) query.

AFAIK, In C# this would be fairly easy. I'd use the `SqlConnection` class and in the connection string set `Encrypt` and `TrustServerCertificate` to `true`. Is there a way to do this in C++ with similarly low effort, a free library maybe?

I know *OpenSSL* is basically able to do this, but I don't need all that *loading a trust store, checking certificate validity, ...* etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use the Microsoft  SQL Server Native Client OLE DB provider, the same principles applies:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131377(v=sql.100).aspx

Look at "SSPROP_INIT_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE".

Comment: I can only assume this would work, because we've decided to do the whole thing another way. This seems to be the most obious solution to the original problem though, therefore the accept.